# How to make a character sit in Unity?

Tags: unity, animation

So I've got the animation, it has root motion but activating it in the settings doesn't seem to do much.

[image]

What would be a good **optimized** way to have the character sit on the stool with the animation matching the movement? Would I need to do it through code?And if that's the case, could I specify in which frame do the movement? Or add a second animation that is in charge of Root Motion?

I know either of these two options I give could work but I'm checking to see if there is a better way or if I'm missing something here.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Following DMGregory's comment I disabled the collider to see if it improved... it did change, but it isn't much better:

[image]

**EDIT 2**: This is how the animation preview looks like (what I'm expecting)

[image]

Then I just hold the last frame while they're sitting and play the animation backwards for when they're getting off - this is just while I get it to work.

Comment: Do you have a collision shape around the counter/stools that's preventing the animation from placing the character onto them? It looks like the character bounces backward as they try to climb onto the stool.

Comment: @DMGregory yes I do, I tried without it and it's still not working as expected, I updated the original post with the gif of how this looks like

Comment: Do you turn the collider back on at the end of the animation?

Comment: No, it was off the whole time

Comment: Can you help us understand then what the source of the backwards motion we see here is? Is your character clipping the collider of the countertop now? Or is this slide offset present in your animations themselves (say, the hip bone is at a different position in the sitting-idle animation than it is at the end of the climb animation)

Comment: I don't understand it myself, but I added a gif of how the animation preview looks like if that helps. The countertop collider doesn't change anything here, it's barely touched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This video helped me a lot:
https://youtu.be/7JEoG4xubP8?t=1319

So what I did was move the character through the script doing a lerp of translation and rotation and turning off all the root motion options EXCEPT in the Animation tool tip of the FBX, scrolling off to almost the end of it and under Motion set the Root Motion Node as `<Root Transform>`.